# Get number of items by class within parent in JS

Tags: javascript

I have built an image gallery where there is one main image and up to 5 thumbnails under it. and can use left and right buttons to cycle through the thumbnails and replace the main image like so:

```
$(".gallery-btn-left").unbind("click").bind("click", function(){
    var image_id = $(".gallery-main-image img").attr('data-id');
    image_id--;
    if(image_id == 0){image_id = $('.gallery-thumbnail img').length;}
    var image_url = $(".gallery-thumbnail img[data-id=" + image_id + "]").attr('src');
    $(".gallery-main-image img").attr('src', image_url);
    $(".gallery-main-image img").attr('data-id', image_id);
});
$(".gallery-btn-right").unbind("click").bind("click", function(){
    var image_id = $(".gallery-main-image img").attr('data-id');
    image_id++;
    if(image_id > $('.gallery-thumbnail img').length){image_id = 1;}
    var image_url = $(".gallery-thumbnail img[data-id=" + image_id + "]").attr('src');
    $(".gallery-main-image img").attr('src', image_url);
    $(".gallery-main-image img").attr('data-id', image_id);
});
```

This all works fine, however, if I want to put two galleries on the same page I get an issue where by my JS is getting `10` instead of `5` or however may thumbnails there are (max 5 per gallery) for `$('.gallery-thumbnail img').length` which is expected.

What I want to know is if there is a way to get the length of the amount of thumbnails in the parent gallery rather than how many thumbnails there are on the page as a whole.

Comment: you should have unique id or something for parent

Comment: Do you have a parent container around the gallery?

Comment: @RAVIPATEL I can't do that unfortunately as the whole thing is being generated from PHP. I query my DB and pass an array of images to a php function that creates the HTML for the gallery.

Comment: @BenM each gallery has a parent div with `class="gallery"` but I cannot give each a unique id for the same reason as the comment above

Comment: @PaddyHallihan `$(this).parents('.gallery').find('.gallery-thumbnail img')` should return the correct length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach for multiple instances is to look up to the container instance and then use `find()` within that instance.

Also when you look for the same selector multiple times it is best to store  a reference to it rather than search the DOM every time you need to access it. It also makes the code a little easier to read

Something like:

```
$(".gallery-btn-left").unbind("click").bind("click", function() {
  var $gallery = $(this).closest('.MAIN-GALLERY-CLASSNAME'),
      $mainImg = $gallery.find(".gallery-main-image img"),
      $thumbs = $gallery.find('.gallery-thumbnail img'),        
      image_id = $mainImg.attr('data-id');

  image_id--;
  if (image_id == 0) {
    image_id = $thumbs.length;
  }
  var image_url = $thumbs.filter("[data-id=" + image_id + "]").attr('src');
  $mainImg.attr({'src': image_url, 'data-id',image_id});

});
```